# Solver Window Resize in Mac Office 2011

Tags: macos, ms-office

For what ever reason the Solver add-in for Mac Office's Excel 2011 produces the following dialog box when attempting to add a constraint to Solver:

[image: Add Constraint Dialog]

Does anyone have a similar problem? Or know how to rectify this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you provide more info about your machine and specifications?

Comment: Hi @Robuust, I am afraid the machine I had this issue on was stolen. It was a late 2010 Mac Pro running Lion.

It was over a year since I had this issue but I believe a re-install of Solver corrected the issue